# A pattern for BBP-type pi formulas? One for order 28?

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics, pi

The original BBP pi formula is

$$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^{4n}}\left(\frac{4}{8n+1}-\frac{2}{8n+4}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+6}\right)$$

Others are:

**Order 4.** Let $P_k = 4n+k$

$$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\color{blue}{2^{2n}}}\left(\frac{2}{P_1}+\frac{2}{P_2}+\frac{1}{P_3}\right)$$

**Order 8.** Let $Q_k = 8n+k$

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{\color{blue}{2^{4n}}}\left(\frac{2^3}{Q_2}+\frac{4}{Q_3}+\frac{4}{Q_4}-\frac{1}{Q_7}\right)$$

**Order 12.** Let $R_k = 12n+k$

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\color{blue}{2^{6n}}}\left(\frac{2^5}{R_2}+\frac{24}{R_3}+\frac{4}{R_6}+\frac{3}{R_9}+\frac{2}{R_{10}}\right)$$

**Order 16.** Let $S_k = 16n+k$

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2^5}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\color{blue}{2^{8n}}}\left(\frac{2^7}{S_2}+\frac{2^6}{S_3}+\frac{2^6}{S_4}-\frac{2^4}{S_7}+\frac{2^3}{S_{10}}+\frac{4}{S_{11}}+\frac{4}{S_{12}}-\frac{1}{S_{15}}\right)$$

**Order 20.** Let $T_k = 20n+k$

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2^6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\color{blue}{2^{10n}}}\left(\frac{2^9}{T_2}-\frac{160}{T_5}-\frac{2^7}{T_6}-\frac{2^3}{T_{10}}-\frac{2^3}{T_{14}}-\frac{5}{T_{15}}+\frac{2}{T_{18}}\right)$$

**Order 24.** (*known*)

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2^5}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\color{blue}{2^{12n}}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{23} \frac{a_k}{24n+k}\right)$$

**Order 28.** ($\color{red}{unknown}$)

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2^{(?)}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\color{blue}{2^{14n}}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{27} \frac{b_k}{28n+k}\right)$$

**Order 32.** (*known*)

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2^{12}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\color{blue}{2^{16n}}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{31} \frac{c_k}{32n+k}\right)$$

where $a_k,c_k$ are integers and can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html).

> **R**: However, what (if any) is the sequence of integers $b_k$ such that **order 28** is true?

**P.S.** I tried *Mathematica's* Integer relations feature but couldn't find any, though I may have used too little decimal precision.

Comment: Goodness, 27 rational functions added up hm?  I hope the Order 32 formula wasn't found by brute force.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Some of the $a_k, c_k$ are zero. The sequence $a_k$ has 11 non-zero terms, while $c_k$ has 16 terms. Yes, makes you wonder how they found order 32.

Comment: Hm, after some persistence, turns out there is indeed an order 28 that uses 21 terms. As it seems there is a general form for order $4m$, perhaps I'll post a new question in mathoverflow and link it here.

Comment: @Simply: As you can get [closed form formulas](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(28k+%2B+a)+2%5E(-14+k)+(-1)%5Ek+for+k+from+0+to+infinity) for the individual summands (also, they converge fast, so you could just numerically estimate the sum), the problem becomes "find an integer linear combination of these 27 real numbers that sums to the desired value", which is a standard application of lattice reduction.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yes, after I increased the precision (and a rather long wait), Mathematica was able to find a relation using 21 terms (plus the pi term). It seems these BBP-type pi formulas have a general form though.

Comment: @Tito: I'm surprised you had a long wait; I got a quick result (using wolfram cloud) by invoking `FindIntegerNullVector[Prepend[Out[1], \[Pi]], 2^18]` where `Out[1]` is the relevant table of (symbolic) values of `(1/28) HurwitzLerchPhi[-1/16384, 1, a/28]`.

Comment: (nevermind my comment; the solution I got was simply unrolling the order 4 solution by a factor of 7)

Comment: @Hurkyl: I'm using an old Mathematica version and an old laptop.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I searched for a solution. Fortunately, all the coefficients are powers of two.

$$
π≟\frac{1}{2^{12}}\sum_{k=0}^∞\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{14n}}\left(\frac{8192}{28 n+1}+\frac{8192}{28 n+2}+\frac{4096}{28 n+3}-\frac{2048}{28 n+5}-\frac{2048}{28 n+6}-\frac{1024}{28 n+7}+\frac{512}{28 n+9}+\frac{512}{28 n+10}+\frac{256}{28 n+11}-\frac{128}{28 n+13}-\frac{128}{28 n+14}-\frac{64}{28 n+15}+\frac{32}{28 n+17}+\frac{32}{28 n+18}+\frac{16}{28 n+19}-\frac{8}{28 n+21}-\frac{8}{28 n+22}-\frac{4}{28 n+23}+\frac{2}{28 n+25}+\frac{2}{28 n+26}+\frac{1}{28 n+27}\right)
$$

---

If you have `Mathematica` you can use this code to do a quick numerical verification.

```
rank = 28;
P[k_] := rank*n + k;
vars = {
    8192, 8192, 4096, 0, -2048, -2048, -1024, 0, 512, 512, 256, 0, 
    -128, -128, -64, 0, 32, 32, 16, 0, -8, -8, -4, 0, 2, 2, 1
};
sum = Inactive[Sum][
    (-1)^n Sum[vars[[i]]/P[i], {i, 1, rank - 1}]/2^(rank*n/2),
    {n, 0, Infinity}
]
N[Activate[sum]/2^12 - Pi, 100]
```

---

### Update1

This is a real 28th-order solution, and each element is linearly independent. You will find that the 16th-order and 32nd-order solutions in the original article also have similar structures.

So I chose a power of 2 for my search space.

---

### Update2

I'll try to give a simple proof:

The original structure can be written as:

$$
P_{28}=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}(-1)^n 2^{-14 n-12} \underset{m=0}{\overset{27}{\sum }}\frac{(1-i)^{25-m}+(1+i)^{25-m}}{m+28 n+1}
$$

Consider the following function:

$$
\int_{1-i}^{1+i} t^{-m-28 n-2} \, \mathrm{d}t=\frac{(1-i)^{-m-28 n-1}-(1+i)^{-m-28 n-1}}{m+28 n+1}
$$

Then the internal summation can be written as:

$$
\frac{(1-i)^{25-m}+(1+i)^{25-m}}{m+28 n+1}=\int _{1-i}^{1+i}-(2 i)^{14 n+13} t^{-m-28 n-2}\, \mathrm{d}t
$$

The parameter of the coefficient is $n$, extracted to the outer layer:

$$
P_{28}=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}-(-1)^n×(2 i)^{14 n+13}× 2^{-14 n-12} \underset{m=0}{\overset{27}{\sum }}\int _{1-i}^{1+i} t^{-m-28 n-2}\, \mathrm{d}t
$$

coincidentally:

$$
-(-1)^n×(2 i)^{14 n+13}× 2^{-14 n-12}=-2i
$$

That is to say:

$$
P_{28}=-2i\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\underset{m=0}{\overset{27}{\sum }}\int _{1-i}^{1+i} t^{-m-28 n-2}\, \mathrm{d}t
$$

Swap the order of summation again, starting from the inner level:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{28}
&=-2i\int _{1-i}^{1+i}\underset{m=0}{\overset{27}{\sum }} \underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}t^{-m-28 n-2}\, \mathrm{d}t\\
&=-2i\int _{1-i}^{1+i}\underset{m=0}{\overset{27}{\sum }} \frac{1}{t^{m+2}-t^{m-8 n-2}}\, \mathrm{d}t\\
&=-2i\int _{1-i}^{1+i}\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t-1}\right)\, \mathrm{d}t\\
&=-2i×\frac{iπ}{2}\\
&=π
\end{aligned}
$$

The final step is a Cauchy principal value integral.

Comment: Wow. Would this provide some hint how to find a proof? I did not really try but would expect something similar for yours. https://www.slideshare.net/joliverlafont/zero-relations-13077017

Comment: I am afraid your formula is not really new, but just the order 4 formula taken in groups of 7 blocks. It has the same pattern every 4 terms: 2^k, 2^k, 2^(k-1), 0.