# A general BBP-type pi formula of order $4m$?

Tags: number-theory, pi

(*This supersedes an [older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343941/a-pattern-for-bbp-type-pi-formulas-one-for-order-28).*) We have the BBP-type pi formulas,

**Order 4.**

$$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\color{blue}{4^{n}}}\left(\frac{2}{4n+1}+\frac{2}{4n+2}+\frac{1}{4n+3}\right)\tag1$$

**Order 8.**

$$\pi = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{\color{blue}{4^{2n}}}\left(\frac{2^3}{8n+2}+\frac{4}{8n+3}+\frac{4}{8n+4}-\frac{1}{8n+7}\right)\tag2$$

> **Q:** In general, for order $4m$ and positive integer $m$, is it true that,
>   $$\large\pi = \frac{1}{4^{m-1}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{mn}}{4^{mn}}\Big(A_1+A_2+A_3\Big)$$

where,

$$A_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^k\, \Big(\frac{2^{2m-2k-1}}{4mn+4k+1}\Big)$$

$$A_2 = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^k\, \Big(\frac{2^{2m-2k-1}}{4mn+4k+2}\Big)$$

$$A_3 = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^k\, \Big(\frac{2^{2m-2k-2}}{4mn+4k+3}\Big)$$

The case $m=7$ yielding order $28$ then answers the [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343941/a-pattern-for-bbp-type-pi-formulas-one-for-order-28).